# PHP what kind of format date time 6 digit Entry date example "733562"

Tags: php, date, datetime, time, unix-timestamp

Hello I'm trying to crack the database of the old mysql data of the previous programmer, I have seen its date format just
"733562"
.anyone know what kind of date format is this "733562"?
date_timestamp output is like

```
$date = date_create();
echo date_timestamp_get($date); //1272509157
echo time(); // 1536470303
```

its very different with that 6 digit date, thank you very much in advance

EDIT 1:

*the data column name is "Birth Date" with example inputed data "733562"

Comment: Time since the start of the DB or some other origin.

Comment: With the date on the database of 733562, can you see in the system what that persons date of birth is?  This may help in working it out.

Comment: Yes, please give us what is Date show in User view ??

Comment: Possibly days since year 0.

Answer (score 1):

I think that difference date form an Origin Date in somewhere.

[image]

Ex:

Origin Date: 1536471483

Value In Row: 733562 
=> Date = 1536471483 +/- 733562;

https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: the data column name it says "Birth Date" with example inputed data "733562", I dont think this is an ID of another table

Comment: It didn't ID, I tould you, ex: Origin date is (Origin)1536471483 -/+ (Value)733562 = (Date in this row). this is what I mean.

Comment: @KrisVer : That column name is important information. You should have included in your question. Some information about just what else is in the DB would be nice too.

Comment: Why don't you include your column name in your question?